# Primefaces paginator template showing page number

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In the following code, paginator template default showing number is (1 to 10). I wanna set default showing number (1 to 5).

```
<p:dataGrid  var="faq"  value="#{faqBean.faqList}"
                    paginatorPosition="bottom" paginator="true" 
                    rows="1" lazy="true" columns="1" layout="grid" 
                    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                    rowsPerPageTemplate="1,5,10,30,60"
                    rowIndexVar="index">
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your question, but if you want to show 5 rows per page, you have to put `rows=5` instead `rows=1`. If you want the user can change the rows per page, use a back bean property, something like `rows=#{youBean.yourProperty}`